# How to access child views and their attributes?

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I am developing an iOS app using Rubymotion. I need to access a child label of a view to change it´s text.

How can I access child views (and their attributes) to modify them?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a `subviews` property on the `UIView` class.

Comment: I think I will go with tagging?

Comment: You can definitely do that, but why not subclass UIView and add properties?

Comment: Sounds interesting, how can I do that?

Comment: are you asking how you can make a subclass of UIView?

Comment: No, but how to add properties? attr_accessor?

Comment: attr_accessor is what you want with RubyMotion. @property is Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Xcode (Interface Builder) to design your views, then you'll want to use tagging to access your subviews.  There are no `properties` in RubyMotion.  It is possible to use `attr_accessor` to define the setter/getter for a property, but then there is no way to tell Interface Builder how to associate the control with the property name since Xcode doesn't understand the Ruby code.  I have had success taking a project that was first written in Objective-C and using the `.xib` and `.storyboard` files in a RubyMotion project.  In that case, if you create `ivars` with the same names as the properties in Objective-C, then everything will work.

If you are creating your `UIView`s programmatically, then you can store each subview in an `ivar` before adding the subview to the view.